# Keypress event is not working for classname of dynamic element created with in javascript

Tags: javascript

In an input field, I don't see value and the keypress event is not triggering to the class name.

Here is my code:

```
var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
input.type = "text";
input.id = 'app_'+i;
input.value = defaultValue;
input.setAttribute('value', defaultValue);
input.setAttribute('class', 'only_numbers');
```

Comment: Where is your keypress event?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? By the looks of your code you are not, so I would recommend removing the jquery tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is dynamically created, so directly asigned events cannot be triggered. So you should change your event declaration to get triggered from document (which exists right from the start):

```
 document.addEventlistener('keypress',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.class == 'only_numbers'){//do something}
 })
```